# Eureka Client Service not reachable on PCF Dev

Tags: netflix-eureka, pcf

Its my first micro-service using PCF Dev. I have created the following Eureka Server App.

```
@EnableEurekaServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class EurekaServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EurekaServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Below are the properties for the eureka-server service

```
eureka-service.register-with-eureka=false
eureka-service.fetch-registry=false
eureka-service.defaultZone=http://eureka-service.local.pcfdev.io/
eureka-service.logging.level.com.netflix.eureka=OFF
eureka-service.logging.level.com.netflix.discovery=OFF
```

Below is the eureka-client service

```
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@SpringBootApplication
public class EurekaClientApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EurekaClientApplication.class, args);
    }
}

@RestController
class ServiceInstanceRestController {

    @Autowired
    private DiscoveryClient discoveryClient;

    @RequestMapping("/service-instances/{applicationName}")
    public List<ServiceInstance> serviceInstancesByApplicationName(@PathVariable String applicationName) {
        return this.discoveryClient.getInstances(applicationName);
    }
}
```

Below are the properties for the eureka-client service

```
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true
eureka.client.fetch-registry=true
eureka.client.defaultZone=http://eureka-client.local.pcfdev.io/
eureka.client.logging.level.com.netflix.eureka=ON
eureka.client.logging.level.com.netflix.discovery=ON
```

I have deployed the micro-services on PCF Dev instance running on my local

[image: PCF Dev Snapshot]

When I run the server & client as Java applications on my local, I can see the response coming from the **service-instances/eureka-client** endpoint. But I get an empty array when I am trying invoke the following endpoint

**http://eureka-client.local.pcfdev.io/service-instances/eureka-client**

When I try to access the eureka-service, using the URL

**http://eureka-service.local.pcfdev.io/**

I get the following response:

```
This site can’t be reached eureka-service.local.pcfdev.io refused to connect.
Search Google for eureka service local pcfdev io
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Thanks in advance.

**Edit-1:**

As per @Barath's comment, I modified the application.properties file for the client application as below but the issue has not still gone. Earlier, I was wrongly referring the client application name in the application.properties file.

```
eureka-client.register-with-eureka=true
eureka-client.fetch-registry=true
eureka-client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://eureka-client.local.pcfdev.io/
eureka-client.logging.level.com.netflix.eureka=ON
eureka-client.logging.level.com.netflix.discovery=ON
```

The bootstrap.properties file for client has the following entry:

```
spring.application.name=eureka-client
```

The bootstrap.properties file for server has the following entry:

```
spring.application.name=eureka-service
```

***Edit-2***

Server: https://github.com/abnig/eureka-service
Client: https://github.com/abnig/eureka-client

Comment: property should be `eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone`

Comment: any path to code ?

Comment: Server: https://github.com/abnig/eureka-service
Client: https://github.com/abnig/eureka-client

Comment: eureka server details are not right. define these two properties `eureka.instance.hostname=eureka-service.local.pcfdev.io
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false`

Comment: FYR [cloud-native](https://github.com/BarathArivazhagan/pivotal-cloud-foundry-microservices/tree/master/spring-cloud-native/basic). Look into pcf profiles on properties to be set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

properties to be defined in eureka server and client are described as below

**eureka-server**

```
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: eureka-service.local.pcfdev.io
  client:
    fetch-registry: false
    register-with-eureka: false
```

**eureka-client**

```
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: https://eureka-service.local.pcfdev.io/eureka
    register-with-eureka: true
    fetch-registry: true
```

please refer [spring-cloud-native](https://github.com/BarathArivazhagan/pivotal-cloud-foundry-microservices/tree/master/spring-cloud-native/basic) for reference

Comment: Now I am able to get the service instances. But when I am hititng the URL http://eureka-service.local.pcfdev.io/eureka I am still getting ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error as in my question. Thanks for the info.

Comment: When you try in broswer don&#39;t include  /eureka that is defualt path only for client.

Comment: Even http://eureka-service.local.pcfdev.io/ gives me the same error. I see that my host already has entry like below, must have been added by PCF Dev:
127.0.0.1       eureka-service.local.pcfdev.io